# Why does the same laptop series use different charger type?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

For a Lenovo laptop, the cheapest model in aseries (in this case L340 (15, AMD)) uses "65W Wall Mount AC Adapter (2pin)-UK" charger whereas the rest uses "65W".

I don't know whether the website is lazy to list the "Wall Mount AC Adapter (2pin)-UK" for the rest.
Assuming that they are different, may I ask why don't they make all of them uses "65W", which I presume to be 3pins?

Comment: Your question is very unclear - even more so as you have not provided links. It would seem likely to me that either charger will work, the difference being one has a cable from the wall to the charger, the other has the charger on top of the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of my ThinkPads over time use an AC cord with two prongs for use in North America. The 2 pin Wall Wart UK is for UK sockets. I carry a UK adapter with me when I travel.

The power of the adapter has nothing to do with the AC Pin Layout. My X1 uses a 45-Watt adapter and my X230 uses a 65-Watt adapter. But either will work on 120 V or 240 V and just need an adapter for the particular country

ThinkPads use 2 pin AC plugs.  Some other manufacturers use 3-pin including ground pin.

So the advertising is for your locale.